# Language translation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Two buttons are there Hindi and English(these are two different categories).

And created one post and content is "How are you?".

When I click the button "Hindi", I need to display this post as in Hindi and When I click the button "English", I need to display this post as in English.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: did u try WPML plugin or Google Language Translator — WordPress Plugins ?

Comment: no.i have no idea abt this

Comment: Check answer but it will translate your full website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using categories for translation but the better way to use some plugin for translation.
Here is the one i have recently used. Using this plugin you can add the language you want.

Check the plugin it might be helpful for you.

Plugin : [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/)

Add language : https://www.screencast.com/t/KdQiqqqES

Add page content in different language : https://www.screencast.com/t/JuEbga8eIE

This plugin won't do automatic translation, you have to add the translated content in admin panel which is best way to describe things in your words, Such plugin are used to avoid any mistakes of translation which automated translation plugin do.

Comment: You have to add that from add language screen and then you need to add translation of each post/page you create in kannada manually.

Comment: how to add new language ?only choosing option is there know?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer also good but 
if you translate just one language to another then you should use this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/

Step 1 go to plugin area add new plugin into search tab paste plugin name Translate WordPress with GTranslate and it will search for you Translate WordPress with GTranslate plugin

**Step 2** click to install button then activate the plugin

**step 3** go to WordPress setting and click on GTranslate menu

**step 4** then pick which language you want to show like Hindi and English

**Step 5** the choose where you would like to show language translated options 
and then save it

check screenshots 
**back end** 
[image]

**front end**

[image]

Comment: If i choose English or Hindi i need to show the post content as respective language.

Comment: it is working fine as you can check it into the screenshot if you will select English  it will show In English and if you select Hindi it will be shown in Hindi

Comment: if it is work then please accept the answer and vote up.

Comment: actually i have one site.In home page two buttons(english and hindi) are there.If i click English,post content will show in English.If i click Hindi,the post content will show in Hindi

Comment: it will need then use the drop down menu instead of your button or you can customize the plugin into buttons instead of a drop-down.

Comment: that i can do.but how i will link to the post page?